# How to email a self generated csv file in Rails without saving it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku

In my Rails application, I create a CSV file using CSV.open block in a model method.

```
class SomeModel
   def self.write_csv
      CSV.open("my_file_name.csv", "w") do |csv|
         ### inserts lines into the file ###
      end
   end
end
```

In my controller, I have an action that sends the file to a user input email address

```
def some_controller_method
   SomeModel.write_csv
   email = params[:email]

   JobMailer.send_csv(email).deliver
end
```

In the `JobMailer`, I directly refer to the file by file name because the `CSV.open` block from `SomeModel.write_csv` saves the file onto disk at the main directory.

```
def send_csv(email)
    attachments['my_file_name.csv'] = {mime_type: 'text/csv', content: File.read(Rails.root.join('your_file.csv'))}
    mail(to: email, subject: 'My subject', body: 'My body.')
end
```

Currently the app will rewrite over the file when a new request comes in, and I believe when I push to production on Heroku, it will automatically delete it after some time.

**To recap:**

1. Generate a CSV
2. Email it via Mailer
3. Remove the file

Can this be done without saving it to disk? Is there a better way?

Comment: in which file you write the 'CSV.open' code ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use CSV#generate class method

```
class SomeModel
   def self.generate_csv
      CSV.generate do |csv|
         ### inserts lines into the file ###
      end
   end
end

def some_controller_method
   csv = SomeModel.generate_csv
   email = params[:email]

   JobMailer.send_csv(email, csv).deliver
end

def send_csv(email, csv)
    attachments['my_file_name.csv'] = {mime_type: 'text/csv', content: csv}
    mail(to: email, subject: 'My subject', body: 'My body.')
end
```

Comment: Hello, I tried exactly what you wrote, but the email I receive has a gibberish attachment, like "YSxiLGMNCg==" for instance instead of the actual CSV I built :(

Comment: @El-Cortez can you share your code to gist.github.com?

Comment: Eventually I was able to make it work here : https://gist.github.com/elcortez/67639eb273b79bf7923b3a76daa65c0d